# One vmware vsan and two data stores

Tags: vmware-vsan

I have five servers in one vsan cluster and one distributed switch. I have two disk groups per server, for a total of ten disk groups. I would like to have the first disk group in each server to contribute to one data store and the other disk group to another data store.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The vSAN architecture creates a single disk group from all hosts/disk groups in the same cluster.